# Is it possible to make one function globally avaiable in php in all apps

Tags: php, linux, symfony

I have the symfony `app` and i have made my one function for `debugging` which want to make avaiable everywhere in all apps

Suppose i have this function

```
function myfunc($var){
echo $var;
}
```

Is there any way i can insert that function in PHP somewhere globally so that my all php scripts can use it if using that php on my server, rather than including it

Comment: Yes, define it at the start of your script, and it will be available everywhere on your site.

Comment: @DainisAbols what about other apps which are not interrelated. I want it to be available like normal php buildin functions

Comment: If you load you whole page through `index.php`, then there shouldn't be a problem. Just make sure, then wherever you are, you page has the same *entry point*.

Comment: @DainisAbols , what if i have 20 sites on same server , each have seprate entry. i am trying to find some way to put that function in some PHP.ini or somewhere where any one can access it. don't know if its possible or not.

Comment: If you don't want to manually include the script containing that function in all sites, then include the script via an auto_prepend_file directive in the php.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this case, you will need to write an extension for php and enable it for your server, that would be the best choice as no Include will needed and can be used at any app on your server ( extension should be enabled from php.ini)

Answer (score 0):

You should not add functions to the `index.php` file. If you want a function to be available everywhere, in Symfony, you can create a [Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html). That will allow you to use it in every application, and to keep the code organized in a way that the Framework understands. If you change the `index.php` file, you may run into problems when updating the framework.